# Printing Tall Images with IE

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, printing

Printing tall images with IE crops the image and only prints one page.

For example:

[image: http://wvs.topleftpixel.com/photos/scotia_plaza_tall_stitched.jpg]

Try a print preview of this image with IE. It prints fine with Google Chrome. I don't want the image to be scaled. Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 3):

Don't print the photo while it is inside the browser.

Right-click on the image and select "save to desktop." Then you can print it directly from Windows and select the options you want (quality, size, etc).